# BHO Toolbar working like Plugin

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, toolbar, bho

I developed IE Toolbar using BHO C#.
I can see the toolbar at the bottom of MEnu with Button.

What this toolbar is do, when enter any url in Address bar that Display me title of the site in message box.

But Now what I want I don't want to display that button (and even toolbar below menu) and it just like working in backround same as other plugin.

so,please any body tell me what changes I need to make to work toolbar just like plugin.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Toolbars and BHOs are two completely separate objects.  They have different registration in the registry, and they are hosted differently by IE.  So, if you don't want a toolbar, just register as a BHO.

Comment: I done same thing register only BHO but it doesn't any affect. I follow the steps from following link : http://msmvps.com/blogs/vcsjones/archive/2010/05/23/writing-a-managed-internet-explorer-extension-part-1.aspx                                        can you guide me what may be I missing ?                                           Thanks

Comment: There is not enough information present for me to offer any further advice.